# NGINX, fascgi, ffmpeg (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I started with [this blog](https://stevethemoose.blogspot.com/2021/07/converting-rtsp-to-mjpeg-stream-on.html) as a starting point. I've got a an rtsp stream I'd like to play on a browser. While it will work, it's sporadic at best, failing more often than not.

server block:

```
server {
  listen 85;
  listen [::]:85;
  server_name _;
  root /var/www/;

  location /streams {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket; 
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param NO_BUFFERING "";
    fastcgi_buffering off;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;  
    }
}
```

Default fastcgi_params file and the bash scripts are the ones in the blog:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-Type: image/jpeg"
echo "Cache-Control: no-cache"
echo ""
ffmpeg -hide_banner -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://UN:PW@IP/live" -vframes 1 -f image2pipe -an    -
```